# SqlPackage.exe Extract inlcudes roles user and permissions

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dac

I am using version `14.0.3811.1` of `SqlPackage.exe`

I am attempting to extract a database, without its User / Role and Role memberships.

I am specifying the properties as per below:

SqlPackage.exe /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:"Foo" /SourceServerName:"foo\bar" /TargetFile:"C:\temp\Extracted\foo.dacpac" /p:ExtractAllTableData=True /p:DacApplicationName=foo.bar /p:DacMajorVersion=1 /p:DacMinorVersion=0 /p:VerifyExtraction=False /p:ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly=True /p:IgnorePermissions=True /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=True

However if I inspect the `model.xml` file in the extracted dacpac file, it has various:

```
<Element Type="SqlRoleMembership">
<Element Type="SqlRole" Name="[Foo]">
<Element Type="SqlUser" Name="[foo]">
<Element Type="SqlLogin" Name="[foo\bar]" Disambiguator="4">
```

Shouldn't the `p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true` `/p:IgnorePermissions=True` and `/p:ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly=True` arguments prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
When publishing the .dacpac file containing these Users / Roles etc, you can use the `/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=` argument to exclude the necessary object types from the deployment.

Comment: `/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=` works only for publish, not for extract
see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-extract?view=sql-server-ver16